# não consigo usar o celular como emulador no android studio

Tags: android-studio

Bom dia!!
Sou novo na área de programação, estou começando agora, comecei um projeto no *android studio 3.4*, no note samsung, processador *intel I3*, fui testar o meu projeto no emulador via USB no meu celular samsung, só que não aparece a opção USB no *android virtual device manager*.
Já ativei a opção do desenvolvedor no celular, instalei o *adb* driver, o USB samsung, o *intel haxm*, coloquei o código `android:debuggable="true"` no *androidManifest.xml*, desinstalei e instalei o android studio e mesmo assim não aparece a opção do **emulador via USB**, criei o *virtual nexus 4 api 27*, *android 8.1 no android virtual*, espero que vocês possam  me ajudar.

Comment: Nas opções de desenvolvedor você habilitou a opção de depuração USB ?

Comment: sim, habilitei sim, mas nada

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você deve ativar o modo desenvolvedor no celular la nas configurações.

Após isso você deve habilitar o modo depuração por USB na aba desenvolvedor (que foi habilitada no passo anterior).

Verifique se a versão do Android do seu aparelho é compatível coma versão na qual você desenvolveu seu projeto.

Verifique se seu cabo USB está dando contato com seu aparelho (já tive problemas de não conseguir devido a isso).

Verifique se seu Android Studio está com alguma atualização pendente.

Caso nada funcione, formate seu aparelho (caso você possa fazer isso).

As vezes que tive o problema com o emulador no celular resolvi dessas formas que informei.

Nunca tive de efetuar instalação de nada e não foi necessário mudar nada no  androidManifest.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: então já fiz tudo isso, e nada, vou tentar ou caba USB, obrigado

Comment: Se o problema não for o cabo, da uma olhada nesses links, pode, ajudar em algo. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device e no https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb , estão falando melhor sobre serviços de execução e sobre o ADB

Comment: será que tem que habilitar alguma coisa coisa na bios?

Comment: Habilitar na BIOS seria para você usar a emulador do Android Studio, mas seria legal verificar sim. Abra a sua BIOS e procure a aba de virtualização e ative ela caso esteja desativada.

Comment: pode ser a versão do android? porque eu usava o android 2.1,dai tive que formatar o meu note e instalei o 3.4.

Comment: Sim pode ser, como eu disse acima, verificar a versão do android.

Comment: obrigado pela sua ajuda